# Error executing SSIS package in SQL Server agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following problem. I have a SSIS Package that works fine when I execute it from visual studio, but when I execute it through the SQL Server Agent it gives me this error (I have it in spanish so I'll translate it and it might be a bit different from the normal message): 
"Can't find connection "{(the id of one of my database connections)}". The Connections collection returns this error when it can't find the specific connection element.".

The SQLSERVERAGENT user has privilegies in the project's folder.

When planning the execution, I used the package file as a origin, if that has something to do.

I ran out of ideas and don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Khor

Comment: Do you have any local connection strings? Like a flat file being accessed localy that is not in a shared folder.

Comment: I finally made it work, I'm gonna write an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work.

The problem was that the user who created the packages had permissions on the server I was accessing with the ODBC to but the SQLSERVERAGENT user didn't.

I changed the user in the SQL Server Agent service from SQLSERVERAGENT to the user who created the packages to make sure that this was the problem and it worked fine, so the solution is either leave the service with this user or give permission on the other server to the SQLSERVERAGENT user.